# How to allow the user to create tasks and set the time when it runs?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, infrastructure

I’m building a project that allows the user to send notifications to his customer.

I want the user to also be able to schedule these notifications to run at a specific time instead right now.

How would I achieve this? What’s the best structure? Should I create a cron job that hits the server every second to check if a task is set at this second?

Comment: I'm thinking of using Hangfire and run background task every second. The task is to check the scheduled notification in the db and once it's time for them to be publish the task will publish them.

Does it make sense to do it this way? or is a check on the db every second sounds 
unnecessary and could be handled better ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own code that runs the tasks by a schedule, but there are already several 3d party tools for that. I would recommend you to have a look at
[Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: Would those guarantee that the task will run? Even if the server has been restarted?

Comment: Yes, they save the list of the to do to their databases

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to capture the details from your customer but in the backend pass on the details to the logic apps or power flow which can be timer based to create a job within those apps. I would recommend power flow as you can use it out of the box where as for logic apps you may have to configure logic apps first. as you tagged the question to Azure i am guessing you are using azure stack.

if not above suggestion may not work for you.

Comment: Is there a way to update the task after it was passed to the logic app?

Comment: you can create a service principle which will establish the communication between web app and the logic app. your backend process can pick up any details input by the user in the DB/app and update the respective logic app job. 
All you need to do is store the logic app job ID in the DB or power flow ID in the DB and compile the XML code before publishing it to the logic app.

Other tool i can think of is the Azure functions. Which actually may be a much better option Following below artile https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function